# What causes this bigger SourceAlpha than SourceGraphic

Tags: svg, dropshadow, svg-filters

I was trying to make the following box have a bigger clickable area:

```html
<svg width="150" height="150">
  <rect x="10.5" y="10.5" width="10" height="10"
        stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

so to do that, I messed around a bit with filters; first I applied a color matrix, and then I wanted to start changing the size of the black background part, but it was somehow already bigger than the original graphic:

```html
<svg width="150" height="150">
  <filter id="fillBlack">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="SourceAlpha" result="blackBox"
        values="0 0 0 0 0
                0 0 0 0 0
                0 0 0 0 0
                1 1 1 1 1"/>
    <feComposite operator="over" in="SourceGraphic" in2="blackBox"/>
  </filter>
  <rect x="50" y="50" width="10" height="10" filter="url(#fillBlack)"
        stroke="transparent" stroke-width="50" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

Now, this seems to come pretty close to my desired result already, but there are two problems: firstly, I really don't understand why this would work, and secondly, because I don't know what causes this, I can't resize the black background.

It seems like the background is always 10% bigger; try changing the values for `width` and `height` on the `<rect>`, and the black background will be a border of 10% the entered width/height around the original box

So what causes the `SourceAlpha` to be bigger, and how do I actually resize the black background so I can have it the size I want?

PS: I'd very much prefer not to put another `<rect>` over the current one, but rather I'd have everything done with a `filter` like what I've got here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the filter region is 10% bigger on all sides.  This is to allow for filter primitives like feGaussianBlur which can make the graphic bigger.

You can change the filter effects region by using the attributes `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` on the `<filter>` element.  They default to -10%, -10%, 120% and 120% respectively.

I recommend reading the [section on filters in the SVG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html).

But even though filters can result in something being drawn larger, it shouldn't change the actual size or shape of the region that responds to pointer events.

There is only one way I can think of that you can use to make the click area larger without adding extra elements.

- Give the shape a large, but invisible, stroke width
- Set `pointer-events="all"`

Setting pointer-events to "all" makes both the stroke *and* fill areas sensitive even if they are invisible.  Compare the behaviour of the squares in this example.

```css
rect:hover {
   fill: orange;
}
```

```html
<svg width="350" height="200">
  
  <rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" fill="red"/>
  
  <rect x="200" y="50" width="100" height="100" fill="green"
        stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="40" pointer-events="all"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: I didn't add the filter to increase the clickable area, I added the larger transparent stroke to increase the clickable area, and the filter is just to make the appearance the same again.

Comment: The approach with `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` defined does seem to work nicely. The second part of your answer is already the approach I used in my 2nd demo though, but thanks for the tip about `pointer-events`.

Comment: Just a follow-up question about this: Do you know why [this](http://jsbin.com/danurilaza/1/edit?html,output) doesn't work in Firefox? It works fine in Chrome, but firefox doesn't make the invisible edge clickable.

Comment: Hmm.. it appears on Firefox that the pointer-events region gets clipped by the filter region.  You can see this if you remove the filter or make the filter region bigger.  I've reported the bug (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1116051).

Comment: Here's a workaround that works in FF.  We make the filter region bigger to cater for the pointer-events region, but restrict the primitive subregion so the filter still looks the same.  http://jsbin.com/wuvogicifa/2/edit?html,output